# Datagrid Textboxes Values not updated with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>` in the `ViewModel`.

```
private ObservableCollectionX<SSYLine> _ssyLines = new ObservableCollectionX<SSYLine>();
    public ObservableCollectionX<SSYLine> SsyLines
    {
        get { return _ssyLines; }
        set
        {
            if (Setter(ref _ssyLines, value, nameof(SsyLines)))
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

So I add a new line like *this*:

```
public void AddNewLine(SSYLine line)
    {
        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            line.PropertyChanged += LinePropertyChangedHandler;                

            SsyLines.Add(line);
            SelectedLine = SsyLines[SsyLines.Count - 1];
        }
    }
```

The PropertyChanged on Class (SSYLine):

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
```

My `XAML` code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SsyLines, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="SsyDatagrid" Grid.Row="1" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
              SelectionChanged="LineSelectionChangedHandler"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLine, Mode=TwoWay}"
              GridLinesVisibility="None" SourceUpdated="SsyDatagrid_SourceUpdated" BorderThickness="0" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" Background="Transparent" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,9,0,0" 
              CurrentCellChanged="LinesDatagrid_CurrentCellChanged">
```

The textbox:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="LineType" Width="Auto"
                                 Text="{Binding detailType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 LostFocus="TextBoxLostFocus"
                                    GotKeyboardFocus="TextBoxGotKeyboardFocusHandler"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" >
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger
                                 Binding="{Binding ExplicitValidations,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                                            Value="True"  >
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Later on, I fetch some data from the `database` and for each record I add a line in the `ObservableCollection`.
I have 4 records. 4 rows are correctly being created, but none of the `textboxes` has a value.
The `ObservableCollection` is correct, with the correct data. The problem only persists on `TextBox` values.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any Binding error in output console?

Comment: Yes i get the following output:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'detailType' property not found on 'object' ''SSYLine' (HashCode=46769243)'. BindingExpression:Path=detailType; DataItem='SSYLine' (HashCode=46769243); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='LineType'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Where is the property `detailType` defined? It's obviously not a member of `SSYLine`. Also keep in mind that you can't bind to fields. `detailType` must be a public property.

Comment: After further investigation I found that detailType was declared as DetailType in the class. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "SSYLine" class you must have the detailType property declared:

```
public string DetailType {set; get;}
```

if it is a string ofc.

And it should start with upper case.

Comment: yes you are correct! I found that detailType was declared as DetailType in the class. Thank you so much.